# なんだこの「ギャラリー」？ What does he mean by gallery?

Tags: meaning, loanwords

[Panel this is taken from for context. This is commentary about a school go tournament that will start soon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyRGh.png)

> あれ　おまえも見にきたの？
>
> なんかギャラリー多いな
>
> 海王中囲碁部はトップレベルだもん
>
> 見なきゃソンだよ

My translation attempt:

> Oh, you came to look too? There's so much at this gallery [??] [Attempt 2: There's so much to see] [Attempt 3: So many people are here to watch]
>
> The Kaiou Middle School Go Club is at a top level, so it would be a loss if you don't look.

I am wondering if maybe there is some Japanese usage of gallery that I am missing?

Fake EDIT: [Judging from weblio I wonder if it might be sense 3:](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%AE%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC)

> ③ ゴルフ・テニスなどの観客。また，観客のいる場所。
>
> 3: Spectators for golf, tennis and so on. Also, a place where spectators gather.

If that's the case, then I think my attempt 3 is on the right track but I am not sure.

Comment: I shouldn't answer in the comments, but I figured there might be someone with a more complete and interesting answer than just "yeah, you've got the idea". If no one shows up to provide a more useful answer, I will go ahead later and put my comment in the answer section.

Comment: actually, you are prefectly allowed to go ahead and put your own answer in the answer section, there's even a badge for doing that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I may be right that in this case ギャラリー多いな means a lot of people gathered to watch, since sense 3 of ギャラリー according to Weblio is ゴルフ・テニスなどの観客 "spectators for golf, tennis and so on" as I said above. Since this is about a gathering at a go tournament, this interpretation seems to make the most sense.

Comment: English 'gallery' has a similar sense - 'the people watching some sort of event', extended from the place where people sit to watch.